# Vultr virtual cpu vs DigitalOcean Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz

Tags: cpu, virtual

When I run a uname -ar command on Vultr command line I see the following:

> Linux my.vultr.account.com 4.12.10-coreos #1 SMP Tue Sep 5 20:29:13
>   UTC 2017 x86_64 Virtual CPU a7769a6388d5 GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

On DigitalOcean I get:

> Linux master 4.11.11-coreos #1 SMP Tue Jul 18 23:06:59 UTC 2017 x86_64
>   Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2650 v4 @ 2.20GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux

I don't know what the difference means?  Is virtual cpu worse/same/better than what I see in DigitalOcean output of "Intel(R) Xeon(R)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real Intel Xeon E5-2650 v4 is a CPU with 12 cores. Depending on your VPS configuration you get X amount of cores assigned from that CPU. Hence virtual CPUs.

Pertaining the specs of Vultr. The official response from Vultr support:

> "We do not provide specific information on the CPUs we offer. They are all late-model Intel Xeon CPUs."

The a7769a6388d5 is a 2.4Ghz virtual CPU. According to:

```
wget freevps.us/downloads/bench.sh -O - -o /dev/null|bash
```

From there on it can be a diversity of 2.4GHz Intel E5 Xeon's from either V2, V3, V4 generation. You can get down to the bottom of it:

```
cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 2 = Broadwell? etc.

**Tip:** CPU speed is not the best way to compare your VPS though. Focus more on I/O speed, datacenter location, uplink speed and ping times.

Comment: Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 2 is a Broadwell chip according to this: http://srbase.my-firewall.org/sr5/cpu_list.php